# android integrating new facebook sdk 3.0.1 and perform login

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I'm trying to upgrade facebook sdk to version 3.0.1 and encountered troubles while performing login. The access token that I'm getting in my session after the login is ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED and I don't know why.

Here is the login code:

```
if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(SplashScreen.this).setCallback(new StatusCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                        if (session.isOpened()) {
                            loginIfSuccessfullAuth(true);

                    }
                }));
            }
```

The session inside the internal if contains access token ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED

Comment: Could it be so that it's just not printed out? What are you putting to LogCat?

Comment: I'm seeing it in the debugger not in the logcat

Comment: Well, what do you see if you use LogCat, and print out ``session.getAccessToken()``? It should return null if none exists.

Comment: I think that my problem might be that I'm trying to login with unsigned app(I didn't signed it with the hash key)

Comment: Hi, did you find resolution to the problem? I have the same issue, but my signing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing `ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED` in your log, make sure you are printing `session.getAccessToken().getToken()`. If you write `session.getAccessToken()` to the log the AccessToken-object's `toString`-method will be called, which will replace the actual token with `ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED`.